# Is there any scenario where you'd want a virtual function instead of a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I was studying virtual functions and base/virtual classes and it seems like there would be no scenario where you would use a virtual function in the base class instead of a pure virtual one.

Comment: One of the possible scenarios is when your base class provides a default implementation of that virtual function, i.e. the base class is not an abstract one and you can create an object of it.

Comment: Base class can also be a perfectly valid object on it's own. And Functionality, of which, could be extended, and overridden, with inheritance.

Comment: There are several kinds of use cases. As mentioned, the typical case is a default behavior that can be modified by a subclass (note this includes a subclass written by a different developer using your code as a library, for example). Another kind is to provide "extension points" or callbacks. E.g. consider an order processing class, it can have an `on_order_complete` method that does nothing (but is not pure) which a subclass can customize. You can even have classes full of empty virtual methods that allow for customization of different parts of its behavior.

Comment: Note that it can also sometimes make sense to define a function as pure virtual in a base class but *still provide an implementation*. This forces derived classes to reimplement/override the function, but still provides a base impletation that the derived class can call if needed/wanted.

Comment: Virtual functions that aren't pure are difficult to document correctly. They have their use but a beginner should probably only write pure virtual functions at first.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, the base class has a default behavior, but you can still change the behavior by making the function virtual in base class.

Let's say, there are 10 functions in the base class and they are all virtual. In your derived class, you only need to override the functions that you want to, no need to override all 10 functions. It makes the implementation of the derived class easier.
- you don't need to override all 10 functions.

Comment: It should be added to the answer, that in fact you *must* mark the method as `vritual` if you want to override it. Maybe the OP thinks that this is optional and `virtual` is like `abstract` in Java, which is not the case.